# Rename '15 puzzle' to 'sliding puzzle'

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Could we rename the tag as I (and probably others) are not familiar with it being called 15 puzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the tag [sliding-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle) and synonymized [15-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/15-puzzle) into it.

I don't think that the [15-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/15-puzzle) tag should be removed, since there are a lot of people who do know them by this name, but the more generic [sliding-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle) is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I had to wait 10 minutes just to accept your answer. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: The delay is there to prevent OPs from accepting the first answer that comes in without considering other feedback. It's mostly useful on the main site, and was originally introduced to help address [the Fastest Gun in the West problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). (In almost all cases, it's helpful to have it there.)

Comment: Couldn't there be a warning (like the one when you try answering your own question) instead?

Comment: @ghosts Truth be told, most people don't read warnings, which iirc is the most notable counteragument. I think that's been proposed before on Meta.SE, though, but if not, that would be the place to propose it.